# Passing Image to Controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send Image and ImageName from View to Controller.

Here's how my controller looks:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Add(BoxAddViewModel image)
  {
      //TODO: Add new box
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
```

This is the model:

```
 public class BoxAddViewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [Required]
     [DisplayName("Name")]
     public string Name { get; set; }
     [Required]
     [DisplayName("Source")]
     public HttpPostedFileBase Source { get; set; }

 }
```

And finally the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "BoxManagement", new { @class = "form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @name = "Name"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Source, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <!--Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Source, new { type = "file",}) -->
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Source)
            <input type="file" name="Source" id="Source" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add</button>
    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
}
```

It comes into the Add method and the Name property value is correct but the Source is null.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using the wrong overload of `BeginForm()` and adding route values, not html attributes (always inspect the html your generating). Use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "BoxManagement", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Side note: Remove `new { @name = "Name"}` from your `TextBoxFor()` method. Never attempt to override the `name` attribute generated by the `HtmlHelper` methods unless you want binding to fail (and is this case it does nothing anyway)